# QGIS doesn't truncate labels of point features in print layout

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

I'm trying to create a map that is separated into two pages (say, a A3 layout). I want them to be exactly the same except of the range they cover, so I can later combine them into one larger map (A2).

My problem is that even the option "Allow truncated labels on the edge of the map" is enabled, the label still doesn't show when it doesn't fit, as shown in the figures below. The points in the red boxes are the same dot, but the label of the second one was not shown at all. I have found that this issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32856) but the solution seems to be for linear features.

Can this be solved for point features?

My QGIS version is 3.26.1-Buenos Aires

[image: This is the right edge of page on the left]

[image: This is the left edge of page on the right]

Comment: Maybe sharing your project + data can give us a hint?

Comment: @Babel [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZKyoDTrpIBp2Sn7RUZagtpMDC8HVYJQY/view?usp=sharing) is a minimal example which demonstrate my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to QGIS main window, Layer Styling > Labels. Set the [Obstacle Weight](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#obstacles) to `Low`.

Then the labels appear:

[image]

Comment: But the point of the yellow layer is to prevent the label to cover things I want to show, that's why I set the obstacle weight higher.

Comment: OK, it's difficult to know how to get the desired effect without knowing the whole project. Often, placing labels manually is faster and produces better results - high quality maps still use this as best practice. Be aware of automatization trap - you can automatize a lot, but sometimes still manual work is better.